# Find all the polynomials f which satisfies the conditions

Tags: polynomials

Find all the polynomials f such that f(2t) can be written as a polynomial in f(t), i.e. for which there exists a polynomial h such that f(2t) = h(f(2t))

This question is from the book Polynomials. I have thought about this problem but could not find any proper approach to it so I saw the solution but still couldn't quite grasp it. So it would be great if anybody could further elaborate the proof or give any other proof.

[image]

Could somebody also tell me how or why is that (2^n)ant^n....a0 equal to the next step i.e. uant^n+.....(ua0+v)

Comment: If $f(t) = a_n t^n + \ldots + a_1 t + a_0$, then $f(2t) = 2^n a_n t^n + \ldots + 2 a_1 t + a_0$ and $u f(t) + v = u a_n t^n + \ldots + u a_1 t + u a_0 + v$.

Comment: OH Yeah. Damn, I didn't think in that manner. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant, he proved that $h$ is linear, that is $h:t\mapsto ut+v$. On the other hand, $f:t\mapsto a_nt^n+\cdots+a_1t+a_0$. So the equality $f(2t)=h(f(t))$ writes
\begin{align*}
f(2t)&=a_n(2t)^n+\cdots+a_2(2t)+a_0\\
&=2^na_nt^n+\cdots+2a_1t+a_0\\
&=h(f(t))\\
&=uf(t)+v\\
&=u(a_nt^n+\cdots+a_1t+a_0)+v\\
&=ua_nt^n+\cdots+ua_1t+ua_0+v.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

That step is simply $f(2t) = h(f(t))$ written out with an assumed form $f(t) = a_nt^n +\dots+ a_0$ and $h(t) = ut+v$. Just write it all out and it will be clear.